# after installing node version 16.16.0 in windows 11 it is showing error in npm --version command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x34u4.png)

```
    npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module './internal/re'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\←[4mnpm←[24m\node_modules\←[4msemver←[24m\index.js:2:20)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\semver\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

I have already restarted my pc after installing
I have already tried uninstalling and then installing again

please help!!!

Comment: Try ```npm cache clean --force```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` if not deleted.
2. Run `npm cache clean --force`.
3. Run `npm install --force`.